# Library version, API version and soname: how should these be named?

Tags: linux, libraries, version

Suppose I have a library called `libfoo` and

- its version is `0.4.2`
- where `0.4` is the API version and
- `2` is the release number which may add new API functions.

Should the soname be `libfoo.so.0.4`, `libfoo.so.0.4.2` or something else?

Answer (score 4):

If api version is `0.4`, and it is incompatible with other `0.*` versions then you should set soname to `libfoo.so.0.4`. Actually soname can be any string, it is only needed to find proper shared library in your system when loading executable.

Many packages (or distros) follow naming scheme different from yours. For example libfoo version `0.4.2` with api `0.4` would become `libfoo.so.4.2` with soname `libfoo.4`.

And when making substantial change to interface, requiring not just recompiling and minor correction here and there, but a lot of code rewrite in code using the library - bump the "major" major version by renaming library. 
Then `libfoo.4.2` turns into `libfoo-1.so.0.1` when bumping version from `0.4.2` to `1.0.1`.

Such scheme makes it easier to install several versions of your library if some old software was not yet rewritten to totally new api.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly you create file libfoo.so.0.4.2 and symlink libfoo.so.0 -> libfoo.so.0.4.2

Comment: I've the sysmlinks `libfoo.so`, `libfoo.so.0.4.0`, `libfoo.so.0.4.1` but what should be the soname of the library.